# @Transactional on controller method not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, controller

In my Spring MVC application, I have a method in a controller that needs to save a bunch of objects (built from an uploaded file) to a database. Let us leave aside for the moment the whole question about whether transactions should be done in the controller or service layer -- the point is that it should technically be feasible to do it in the controller, but I am finding problems.
If you look at the code below, what I am expecting is that if any of the three calls to saveContact fails with an Exception (any exception, since I put rollbackFor = Exception.class ), then all three should be rolled back. Still, what I see is that if for example the third one fails, the data from the first two is still present in the database. The exception thrown is a PersistenceException, so I believe this should trigger the rollback, but it doesn't (it bubbles up to the client's browser, which is what I expected since I'm not catching it).

```
code removed for security reasons
```

Thanks

Comment: `@Transactional` on that method doesn't have any added value as it is an internal method call. Spring uses proxies and only calls into the object pass thorough the proxy. Also your code is flawed you shouldn't catch and swallow exceptions as that interferes with the tx support (it relies on transactions to determine to rollback or not, currently there is never an exception hence always tries to commit). Finally you are using MySQL make sure that you are using table types that actually supports transactions (MyISAM tables don't have tx support).

Comment: I doubt that putting Transactional annotation on Controller level is even good practice. I thought it better goes for Service level. See this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/spring-transactional-annotation-best-practice )

Comment: @StevePark No doubt about that. However, as I said in my question, the point is that it is technically feasible, and what I am trying to understand here is why it is not working. Indeed, putting it in the service layer does not solve the problem in itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that was a good pointer. I tried moving transactional up to the controller endpoint, and indeed it worked. However that was ugly :) so I ended up reorganizing things, so the transaction is not in the controller anymore. Would you convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` on that method doesn't have any added value as it is an internal method call (and your class is already transactional). Spring uses proxies and only calls into the object pass thorough the proxy.

Also your code is flawed you shouldn't catch and swallow exceptions as that interferes with the tx support (it relies on transactions to determine to rollback or not, currently there is never an exception hence always tries to commit).

Finally you are using MySQL make sure that you are using table types that actually supports transactions (MyISAM tables don't have tx support).

I would however strongly suggest to move the transactional part (or the business logic which you are now doing in your controller) to a service. The controller (or web layer in general) should only be a thin layer converting the incoming request into something useable for the service layer and the result into something useable for the web to display.

Answer (score 2):

With proxy-target-class="true" you're telling spring to use cglib to handle the proxying but you've specified scoped-proxy="interfaces".

See 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15568457/117839

Comment: the proxy-target-class="true" was added because without it I get the following error:
    Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The mapped controller method class 'ch.oligofunds.oligoworld.web.ExcelUploaderImpl' is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69'. If the controller requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.

I'm trying to understand this: I cannot use both together?

Comment: Ok, so I first tried removing the proxy-target-class="true" in web-context.xml (and in dao-context.xml), leaving only scoped-proxy="interfaces". As said before, I get the error mentioned in the comment above. Then, I put the proxy-target-class="true" back, and I modified the controller by removing the "implements ExcelUploader" and all the @Override annotations (so now the interface is not being used at all). Here things run, but the transaction is still not working (the first two insertions still show up in the DB when the third fails).