# @Bean in @Configration and @Component

Tags: java, spring

What will be the difference between the beans declared with @Bean in @Configration and @Component.
I know there is a difference because of CGLIB.
How many instances in both cases?

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174669/what-is-the-difference-between-configuration-and-component-in-spring

Comment: And these too... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089200/what-is-cglib-in-spring-framework and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903053/difference-between-component-and-configuration-in-spring-3 (Which is answered by @Javaboy)